# iOS : Move forward dynamically NSDate with button

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I have created a custom class for my dates and need move dates forward and backward via button . Here is my code which shows Today date :

```
- (NSString *) showToday {

    NSCalendar *myCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    [dateFormatter setCalendar:myCal];

    offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
//shows today 
    [offsetComponents setDay:0];

    NSDate *nextDate = [myCal dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d"];
    NSString *currDay = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currDay];

    [myCal release];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return currDay;
}
```

on my viewController :

```
customClass = [[customClass alloc]init];

    day.text = [cal showToday];
```

so if I need to move forward a date I just change this line code to :

```
//show tomorrow 
[offsetComponents setDay:1];
```

so How can I dynamically change this line and change dates via button ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare an `int` for your `offsetComponents` variable. then :

```
- (IBAction)moveDatesForward:(id)sender {

    NSCalendar *persCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSPersianCalendar];    
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSLocale *IRLocal = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"fa_IR"];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:IRLocal];
    [dateFormatter setCalendar:persCalendar];

    offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];

    offsetComponents.day = _dayNumber;

    NSDate *nextDate = [persCalendar dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d"];
    dayLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:nextDate];

    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dayLabel];

    [persCalendar release];
    [dateFormatter release];

      _dayNumber ++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about doing something like this:

(Uses ARC - Don't complain about memory leaks.)

```
- (void) refreshDateLabel
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

    self.dateLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: self.date];
}

- (IBAction)forward:(id)sender
{
    self.date = [self.date dateByAddingTimeInterval: 24 * 60 * 60];
    [self refreshDateLabel];
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    self.date = [self.date dateByAddingTimeInterval: -(24 * 60 * 60)];
    [self refreshDateLabel];
}
```

Complete project at https://github.com/st3fan/StackOverflowAnswers/blob/master/DateSelection

Comment: Thank you I am using custom class for creating dates , and I Cant change my codes to something else... would you please modify your answer based on my codes ? thanks